# Looping in rows in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My data frame has first columns as IDs as follows:

```
ID
A123
A234
A456
A123
A234
```

Now I need to create a new column Indicator which will add one in front of each ID which is getting repeated.

Desired Output:

```
ID     Indicator
A123    1
A234    1
A456    0
A123    1
A234    1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple operation in Pandas once you get the hang of it, so you may want to invest some time in a tutorial. What you need to do is call the conventient function `duplicated()` of the `ID` column, an instance of `pandas.core.series.Series`. So:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["A123", "A234", "A456", "A123", "A234"], columns=["ID"])
df.ID.duplicated()
```

---

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: ID, dtype: bool
```

It returns a `Series` with boolean values. You can take that new `Series`and call its `apply` function that will then return a `Series` with values using the return of `apply`. So to turn each boolean into 0 or 1, all you need to do is apply `int`:

```
df.ID.duplicated().apply(int) // or df["ID"].duplicated().apply(int)
```

---

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

There  are lots of other convention functions in `Series`. If you need to do something more complicated, you can `apply()` a custom function, e.g.

```
def custom_function(value):
    return str(int(value))

df.ID.duplicated().apply(custom_function)
```

---

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

You can also use the `apply()` of the `DataFrame` itself to call functions across all rows or columns, specified using `axis`.